# How do I successfully stabilize or trim a TinyWhoop Nano?

Tags: tinywhoop, fine-tuning, trim

I'm a newbie to drone flying and decided to start with a TinyWhoop Nano RTF. I know *just* enough about model aircraft controllers from using them in robotics and animatronics that fine-tuning is necessary to get stable or centered actuators.

In the case of the Nano, I am not sure about the right procedure to trim out the rotors. My expectation was to get it to hover and then use the trim buttons to get it to stop drifting in a particular direction. It would usually drift and hit something before I could manage to figure out what direction needed to be trimmed. I finally put it in a very large open-top cardboard box to stop having to chase it all over the room.

I've gotten it to drift much less, but it still seems to be all over the place when I throttle up more. I've had problems with one of the props scraping the canopy ever so slightly, which is annoying thing to try to fix.

So I guess my question is twofold:

1. What's the specific method to trim a TinyWhoop Nano using the TBS controller that comes with the RTF version; and,
2. Is there a general process for trimming out any new quad, such as how much throttle to use and a clean environment in which to more carefully check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often the really small/simple drones don't trim to completely stable, as their controllers are very basic and the 'step size' on the trim isn't fine enough. And, if you get them to trim, then they will usually drift again as the battery voltage changes - again, due to the simple design.

I usually just get it as close as possible, and accept there will be drift - its good object avoidance practice.

Finally, a tip - if such a small drone *is* going to crash, just stop the props ... this usually results in less (if any) damage to the drone or whatever it hits.